# Package dependencies in a jar

Tags: java, jar, package

I'm trying with a .jar library but the `init` method has a call to slf4j. I have added slf4j to my dependencies Project but I believe that I need to repackage the library with the dependency inside the jar.
The method I'm calling in the jar has this line:

```
private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOG =
       org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(Init.class);
```

But I have this error:

```
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
```

Comment: How are you packaging / building your code? Are you using maven? Can we see your pom?

Comment: The jar i'm using is a java library builded from Maven Central but have this line slf4j but no have any dependency in to jar

Comment: I no have pom, only is added to external libraries slf4j-api-1.7.8.jar; slf4j-api-1.7.9.jar

Comment: you should specify the slf4j-api-1.7.9.jar to the classpath. like: java -cp your-app.jar:lib/slf4j-api-1.7.9.jar your.package.MainClass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need an slf4j implementation, just as your error said. There are multiple. Here are a two:

[slf4j-simple](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple): it prints out to your console/terminal

[log4j-slf4j-impl](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl): The Apache Log4j SLF4J API binding to Log4j 2 Core

If you need just the .jar, choose your needed version and you can download it under files.

If you need more help, [the official manual](https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html) explains it quite good.

Hope I could help you

Comment: Add the 2 libraries slf4j-simple and log4j-slf4j-impl got this error: SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/F:/xx/yy/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.18.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/F:/xx/yy/lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.9.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
So remove log4j-slf4j-impl and compile fine. TNX